# Python: hashed and verified passwords are not the same

Tags: python

I use hash_password function to hash my passwords:

```
def hash_password(self):  
    os_urandom_static = b"ID_\x12p:\x8d\xe7&\xcb\xf0=H1\xc1\x16\xac\xe5BX\xd7\xd6j\xe3i\x11\xbe\xaa\x05\xccc\xc2\xe8K\xcf\xf1\xac\x9bFy(\xfbn.`\xe9\xcd\xdd'\xdf`~vm\xae\xf2\x93WD\x04" 
    salt = hashlib.sha256(os_urandom_static).hexdigest().encode('ascii') 
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', self.password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000) 
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash) 
    return (salt + pwdhash).decode('ascii')
```

To verify passwords I use verify_password, I have added 2 prints at the end of function to check passwords and they are not the same. Where is the problem?

```
def verify_password(self, stored_password, provided_password):
    salt = stored_password[:64]
    stored_password = stored_password[64:]
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', provided_password.encode('utf-8'), salt.encode('ascii'), 100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash).decode('ascii')
    print(pwdhash )
    print(stored_password)
    return pwdhash == stored_password
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. But why make things complicated?

Instead, you could just compare the stored password with the hash of the provided password.

```
import hashlib, binascii

def hash_password(password):
    os_urandom_static = b"ID_\x12p:\x8d\xe7&\xcb\xf0=H1\xc1\x16\xac\xe5BX\xd7\xd6j\xe3i\x11\xbe\xaa\x05\xccc\xc2\xe8K\xcf\xf1\xac\x9bFy(\xfbn.`\xe9\xcd\xdd'\xdf`~vm\xae\xf2\x93WD\x04"
    salt = hashlib.sha256(os_urandom_static).hexdigest().encode('ascii')
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash)
    return (salt + pwdhash).decode('ascii')

stored_password = hash_password("Hello_World123")
print(stored_password)

def verify_password(stored_password, provided_password):
    salt = stored_password[:64]
    stored_password = stored_password[64:]
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', provided_password.encode('utf-8'), salt.encode('ascii'), 100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash).decode('ascii')
    print(pwdhash )
    print(stored_password)
    return pwdhash == stored_password

def verify_password_simple(stored_password, provided_password):
    return stored_password == hash_password(provided_password)

print("verify_password:", verify_password(stored_password, "Hello_World123"))
print("verify_password_simple:", verify_password_simple(stored_password, "Hello_World123"))
print("verify_password_simple:", verify_password_simple(stored_password, "Bad PW"))
```

Output:

```
af756be6069a4bc6b3cfc0ec42aa757ae70395852ff7cacda38d1ab7ba890a896aa3f98243946e4c5910a6317dc1e9d6f1e46b314aab9b038a00ae34dcc9b0887ace6b72a9363974c403372aa93276328091259ee4584e4a7ee950f47dc7d0e4
6aa3f98243946e4c5910a6317dc1e9d6f1e46b314aab9b038a00ae34dcc9b0887ace6b72a9363974c403372aa93276328091259ee4584e4a7ee950f47dc7d0e4
6aa3f98243946e4c5910a6317dc1e9d6f1e46b314aab9b038a00ae34dcc9b0887ace6b72a9363974c403372aa93276328091259ee4584e4a7ee950f47dc7d0e4
verify_password: True
verify_password_simple: True
verify_password_simple: False
```